# Edit text is not expanding upto its background

Tags: android

[image]  I am using the following code in my xml,
  I want to give background to my edittext,the background image is around 400*190 pixels..
  Edittext is only occupying only one line and when on other part nothing is happening.

How to set my Edittext to occupy my background image,so that when I click on anypart of it,it should popup keyboard.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/noteslayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/edittextnotes" > 

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/notes"         
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is confusing me

Comment: please understand,I have image of around 400*194 pixels,I want to give this as a background to my Edit text.I give as mentioned in code.But when I click in middle of that background it is not giving keyboard because edit text is occupying only one line,I dont want to fix that height.How to adjust this

Comment: try drawing it to explain.

Comment: On an entirely unrelated subject, why do you have a _"Back"_ button in your design? Not saying it shouldn't be there. Kinda subjective. But curious to know anyway. Especially, because of this: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to set the background of `EditText` only besides `RelativeLayout` as below:

> ```
>   <EditText
>      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
>      android:id="@+id/notes"         
>      android:maxLines="5"
>       android:lines="5"       <---- set this lines property
>      android:background="@drawable/edittextnotes"    <----See this.
>      android:capitalize="sentences"
>      android:layout_width="250dp"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
> ```

Comment: I tried it,but edittext is starting from the middle of that background and singleline is going on continuesly

Comment: Can you post the screen shot so that i can able to understand what is going wrong ?

Comment: sure,I will post.please try to answer

Comment: please find my edited post

Comment: I have edited my answer checkout and set ` android:lines="5"` property .

Comment: still the text is moving away,not solved

Comment: Have you tried with my EditText ? because i have tried it and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/noteslayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dip"
android:background="@drawable/edittextnotes" > 

<EditText

    android:id="@+id/notes"         
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:capitalize="sentences"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Comment: Its not working,still I am getting the same problem